# Print rows which have same column

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, rows

I am still quite new and stuck in this case.

I have a csv file which is similar with the following.

```
import csv

csvpath = "C:/Test/test.csv"

with open(csvpath) as f:
    csv = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in csv:
        print(row)
```

and the output is:

```
{'NAME': 'John', 'NICKNAME': 'Big John', 'COUNTRY': 'Canada', 'CITY': 'Toronto'}
{'NAME': 'David', 'NICKNAME': 'Small Jogn', 'COUNTRY': 'Canada', 'CITY': 'Toronto'}
{'NAME': 'Alan', 'NICKNAME': 'The Bull', 'COUNTRY': 'England', 'CITY': 'London'}
{'NAME': 'Ethan', 'NICKNAME': 'The Hawk', 'COUNTRY': 'England', 'CITY': 'London'}
{'NAME': 'Ivan', 'NICKNAME': 'The Russian', 'COUNTRY': 'Russia', 'CITY': 'Moscow'}
{'NAME': 'Boris', 'NICKNAME': 'The Bear', 'COUNTRY': 'Russia', 'CITY': 'Moscow'}
```

Is it possible to print first only the rows which have country Canada. Then I want another loop to print rows with countries England and another one for Russia. However the country will be edited all the time so it won't be the same and there might be different countries and number of countries every day in this list. So basically I need to print in different for loops separately the rows which have same countries.

Comment: That's not what a csv file looks like.

Comment: Yes it is csv whcih can be read as dictionary if using ```with open(csvpath) as f:
    csv = csv.DictReader(f)```

Comment: Do you really to print in "different loops" or do you want to print the rows in the file ordered by country?

Comment: @snakecharmerb yes in different loops. First loop to print only rows from one country. 2nd loop to print from another country and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below group the data by countries: (based on the data structure in the question)

```
from collections import defaultdict

data = [{'NAME': 'John', 'NICKNAME': 'Big John', 'COUNTRY': 'Canada', 'CITY': 'Toronto'},
        {'NAME': 'David', 'NICKNAME': 'Small Jogn', 'COUNTRY': 'Canada', 'CITY': 'Toronto'},
        {'NAME': 'Alan', 'NICKNAME': 'The Bull', 'COUNTRY': 'England', 'CITY': 'London'},
        {'NAME': 'Ethan', 'NICKNAME': 'The Hawk', 'COUNTRY': 'England', 'CITY': 'London'},
        {'NAME': 'Ivan', 'NICKNAME': 'The Russian', 'COUNTRY': 'Russia', 'CITY': 'Moscow'},
        {'NAME': 'Boris', 'NICKNAME': 'The Bear', 'COUNTRY': 'Russia', 'CITY': 'Moscow'}]

data_by_country = defaultdict(list)
for entry in data:
    data_by_country[entry['COUNTRY']].append(entry)

for country, info_lst in data_by_country.items():
    print(country)
    for info in info_lst:
        print(f'\t {info}')
```

output

```
Canada
     {'NAME': 'John', 'NICKNAME': 'Big John', 'COUNTRY': 'Canada', 'CITY': 'Toronto'}
     {'NAME': 'David', 'NICKNAME': 'Small Jogn', 'COUNTRY': 'Canada', 'CITY': 'Toronto'}
England
     {'NAME': 'Alan', 'NICKNAME': 'The Bull', 'COUNTRY': 'England', 'CITY': 'London'}
     {'NAME': 'Ethan', 'NICKNAME': 'The Hawk', 'COUNTRY': 'England', 'CITY': 'London'}
Russia
     {'NAME': 'Ivan', 'NICKNAME': 'The Russian', 'COUNTRY': 'Russia', 'CITY': 'Moscow'}
     {'NAME': 'Boris', 'NICKNAME': 'The Bear', 'COUNTRY': 'Russia', 'CITY': 'Moscow'}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the closest answer to my question but is it possible not to read from the dictionary but from the csv as I wrote above using ```with open(csvpath) as f:
    csv = csv.DictReader(f`)```?

Comment: @bbfl Try to read the csv and create the dict. Its a good experience for you.

Answer (score 0):

when they are all together in an array.

```
def print_countries(array,countryname):
 print("results for: ", countryname)
 for item in array:
   if item['COUNTRY'] == countryname:
      print(item)
```

made it a function. If you want to print every country in the CSV file I would build an array with every name.

```
def get_countrynames(array):
 countryname_list = []
 for row in array:
  if row['COUNTRY'] not in countryname_list:
    countryname_list.append(row['COUNTRY'])
 return countryname_list

with open(csvpath) as f:
    csv = csv.DictReader(f)
    names = get_countrynames(csv)
    for country in names:
     print_countries(csv,country)
```

hope this works, not tested myself

Comment: Thanks but as I said countries will be changed every day in the csv file so Canada may not be in the csv file next time.

Answer (score 0):

Selecting items from a collection based on some criterion is known as *filtering*.

Python provides the [filter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) built-in function to do this, or you can use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) or a [generator](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions) expression to achieve the same result.

List comprehensions are faster than `filter`, and are considered to be more "pythonic", but I find `filter` sometimes makes code easier to understand.  Generator expression are syntactically similar to list comprehensions, but use less memory (and can only be looped over once).

The function below shows how to use all three options.  It accepts an open file and a list of country names (as strings) as its arguments and prints out the rows found for each country.

```
import csv

def print_rows(file, countries):
    reader = csv.DictReader(file)
    # Make a list of all the rows so we can loop over them more than once.
    rows = list(reader)
    for country in countries:
        print('Printing rows for', country)

        # Filter the rows by country.
        # Using the filter built-in function.
        filtered_rows = filter(lambda row: row['COUNTRY'] == country, rows)
        # List comprehension.
        # filtered_rows = [row for row in rows if row['COUNTRY'] == country]
        # Generator expression.
        # filtered_rows = (row for row in rows if row['COUNTRY'] == country)
        for row in filtered_rows:
            print(row)
        print()
    return


countries = ['Canada', 'Russia']

csvpath = "C:/Test/test.csv"

with open(csvpath) as f:
    csv = csv.DictReader(f)

    print_rows(f, countries)
```

Output:

```
Printing rows for Canada
{'NAME': 'John', 'NICKNAME': 'Big John', 'COUNTRY': 'Canada', 'CITY': 'Toronto'}
{'NAME': 'David', 'NICKNAME': 'Small Jogn', 'COUNTRY': 'Canada', 'CITY': 'Toronto'}

Printing rows for Russia
{'NAME': 'Ivan', 'NICKNAME': 'The Russian', 'COUNTRY': 'Russia', 'CITY': 'Moscow'}
{'NAME': 'Boris', 'NICKNAME': 'The Bear', 'COUNTRY': 'Russia', 'CITY': 'Moscow'}
```